# How do I center the entire image and left align images inside it?

Tags: html, css

I have an image gallery in a website I'm working on. 
I wanted to center the image gallery, so I added 'text-align:center' to it.
It works fine, but what I wanted was to center the entire image gallery on the page and still to left align images inside it. 
How do I do it?

[image]

HTML

```
<section>
  <article class="img1">
    <a href=""><img src="img/img1.png"></a>
    <dl>
      <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
      <dd>Image Description</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
  <article class="img2">
    <a href=""><img src="img/img2.png"></a>
    <dl>
      <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
      <dd>Image Description</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
  <article class="img3">
    <a href=""><img src="img/img3.png"></a>
    <dl>
      <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
      <dd>Image Description</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
  margin-top: 100px;
  /* the gap between top navigation above */
  text-align: center;
}

.img1,
.img2,
.img3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 1%;
  padding: 0;
}

article img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

article dl {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

article dt {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

article dd {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried `margin: 0 auto;`? And also: what is `margin-left: 0 1%;`??

Comment: @Huelfe Thank you for the editing! Yes, I tried it and it still didn't work. 'margin-left: 0 1%;' was typo, so I edited it now!

Comment: I provided a answer that uses text-align that you already are using. But what browser are you going to support? Could you use flex-box?

Comment: @Erex Thanks for your answer! But, it's still not working. I posted my current layout. Currently, I'm going to support safari. I've never used flex, but if that fixes this problem, I want to use it.

Comment: I updated my answer with a flexbox solution. See if it works, and feel welcom to comment below the answer if it is something that brakes when you try to implement it in your solution

Answer (score 2):

Just change text-align: center; to text-align:left; in main section. You will get your desired layout.Your HTML layout will be same.

```
section {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: left;
}

.img1,
.img2,
.img3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 1%;
  padding: 0;
}

article img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

article dl {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

article dt {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

article dd {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to align the gallery from the parent element, and the images from the gallery element. I do not know what your parent element of the gallery is so I created a div with class image-container. See my solution in plunkr below.

**EDIT:** Updated the CSS to use flex-box insted of text-align. See the comments in the CSS for more information

```css
.image-container{
        /*This CSS centers the whole gallery*/
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    section {
        background-color: lightgrey; /*Just to better show position of element*/
        margin-top: 100px;
        width: 350px; /*This controls what width you want on the gallery*/
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    section > article {
        background: darkgrey; /*Just to better show position of element*/
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 48%; /*This controls how many items that would fit in to a row */
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
    }


    section > article > a {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block; /*This is to make article wrapt the content correctly*/
    }


    article img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    article dl {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    article dt {
        font-size: 0.9em;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    article dd {
        margin-left: 0;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <section>
      <article class="img1">
        <a href=""><img src="img/img1.png"></a>
        <dl>
          <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
          <dd>Image Description</dd>
        </dl>
      </article>
      <article class="img2">
        <a href=""><img src="img/img2.png"></a>
        <dl>
          <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
          <dd>Image Description</dd>
        </dl>
      </article>
      <article class="img3">
        <a href=""><img src="img/img3.png"></a>
        <dl>
          <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
          <dd>Image Description</dd>
        </dl>
      </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Add `text-align: left;` to this selector `.img1, .img2, .img3`.

**Also**

In your work you add `wisth: 100%;` to the `img`. please remove this or add `max-width: 150px;`.

**Like this**

```
article img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```css
section {
    margin-top: 100px; /* the gap between top navigation above */
    text-align: center;
}

.img1,
.img2,
.img3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0 1%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

article img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

article dl {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

article dt {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

article dd {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <article class="img1"> <a href=""><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2d16c2d.jpg"></a>
        <dl>
            <a href="#">
            <dt>Image Title</dt>
            </a>
            <dd>Image Description</dd>
        </dl>
    </article>
    <article class="img2"> <a href=""><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2d16c2d.jpg"></a>
        <dl>
            <a href="#">
            <dt>Image Title</dt>
            </a>
            <dd>Image Description</dd>
        </dl>
    </article>
    <article class="img3"> <a href=""><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2d16c2d.jpg"></a>
        <dl>
            <a href="#">
            <dt>Image Title</dt>
            </a>
            <dd>Image Description</dd>
        </dl>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried it, but images are still centered ;-)

Comment: Can you post your image ??

Comment: @JinsooKang , i update my answer please check now .

Comment: Thanks for the update! But, it's still not working..;)

Comment: is you got the answer form above ?? @JinsooKang

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a `max-width` to the `section` with `margin:auto` to center the whole section on the page and then apply `text-align:left` to align inner inline elements to left...

Also why `.img1, .img2, .img3` in your css if same css for all...Add a custom class in your `section` and use it only once like `.gallery article` or use same class in all `article`

**[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/hs4teqqs/1/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
section.gallery {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  background: grey;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
}

.gallery article {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0 1%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.gallery article img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery article dl {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.gallery article dt {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.gallery article dd {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <article class="img1">
    <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></a>
    <dl>
      <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
      <dd>Image Description</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
  <article class="img2">
    <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></a>
    <dl>
      <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
      <dd>Image Description</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
  <article class="img3">
    <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></a>
    <dl>
      <a href="#"><dt>Image Title</dt></a>
      <dd>Image Description</dd>
    </dl>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: I tired it, but it's still not working. I used a wrapper to center the entire page(margin: 0 auto; width: 95%;) before and would it affect this situation?

Comment: @JinsooKang I have used the `width:80%` to the section with `margin:auto` and its working fine...check updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/pankaj_bhr/q5u6Lbrh/6/),

**CSS:**

```
section {
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display:block;
}
section article {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
}
article img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

Let your HTML as it is, I made some minor changes in image section to make it more clean.you dont need to add `img1, img2...`

Hope this may help you.